# How to check whether a list contains a character in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I am learning lisp and i encountered a problem, I have this code

```
(defun createlist(list)
    (if (characterp (car lst))
        (list (car lst))))

> (print (createlist '(a v a (3))))
```

how do I get a list with a character in it without writing

```
>(print (createlist '(#\a b 1)))
```

Comment: `a` is a symbol, not a character. Use `symbolp` to test for that.

Comment: `(aref "a" 0)` will return a character, but I don't think that's what you're looking for, either. The only way to write a character literal is with the format `#\a`.

Comment: I actually want to pass a list to createlist where it will detect characters like a, b, c etc but I want to pass my list argument as ( a b c 1 2 ) and not ( #\a #\b #\c 1 2) and I just checked my code with symbolp and it gives me ( A B C 1 2) but with characterp it returned null when I first did it. Thanks symbolp works for me.

Comment: why is the function called `createlist` and what should it return?

Comment: It's just a snippet of code, I have been stuck at this very step and I was not able to proceed further. The code will basically take in a list argument and traverse it including nested lists to find characters and put them in a new list and return.

Comment: @Barmar '#\' is short form for `(character ...)`, so one can also do `(character "a")` -> `#\A` or `(character 'a)` -> `#\A`. Or one can do `(coerce "abcd" 'list)`
-> `(#\a #\b #\c #\d)` to obtain a list of characters, too.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim None of those are character literals.

Comment: @Barmar but the result is. And as I see he want to create character with less typing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the only way to write a character literal. If you want to detect `a` as well as `#\a`, you need to check for a symbol whose name is one character long, e.g.

```
(let ((elt (car list)))
  (if (or (characterp elt)
          (and (symbolp elt) 
               (= (length (symbol-name elt)) 1)))
      (list elt)))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(mapcar #'character (remove-if-not #'symbolp '(a b c 1 2)))
;; (#\A #\B #\C)

(mapcar #'list 
        (mapcar #'character 
                (remove-if-not #'symbolp
                               '(a b c 1 2 d))))
;; ((#\A) (#\B) (#\C) (#\D))
```